# Minimum spanning Tree which includes an edge

Tags: algorithm, tree

I want to describe an alorithm;

Let G be a weighted, undericted graph. Given an edge 'e', is there an MST which includes this `e` edge?

> What I did:  I built a graph:
>
> `G'=(V,E') | E={e'|e' -in E\{e} ,w(e')=< w(e)}`
>
> And now I just find if there is a path from u to v (u and v are the two sides of the edge `e`)  using DFS or BFS

What they did was the same but with this change :

**G'=(V,E') | E={e'|e' -in E ,w(e') < w(e)}`**

I still can't understand how there algorithm is true ? Why didn't they exclude e from E ?

Comment: Doesn't the condition w(e') < w(e) imply that e' cannot be e?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Yes it does. But we will still have different conditions.

Comment: Yes you are right, the conditions shall be different. Can you post your algorithm? (what are u and v)

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I did not write a code. I just wrote the idea down which is enough for me ATM. 

In their solution they put a note saying that my algorithm finds out if every MST has the edge `e` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is the same as in Kruskal's algorithm.

**Their Correctness Proof:**
They build a graph that contains edges with edge weights strictly less than `w_e`. If there is already a path from `u` to `v` then `e` cannot be in any MST of G because then `e` would be the largest weight edge in a cycle.
Also, if there is no path yet from `u` to `v` then we can add `e` (as in Kruskal's algorithm) and build an MST containing `e`.

**In your case:**
You find the MST of the graph that does not contain `e` but has edges with weights <= `w_e`. If there is already a path from `u` to `v`, then that path may contain an edge e' having a weight equal to e. So we can replace `e'` with `e` and get an MST. Hence your algorithm checks if `e` is present in **all** MSTs of G.

Comment: If there is already a path from u to v that has an edge e' with weight = w_e, then we can replace e' with e. The vertices that were connected earlier will still remain connected after the replacement.

Comment: I understand now! It's a bit confusing to be honest.
Well explained.